# Retrieive ids from the checked checbox itens in a GridView Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, gridview, mvccontrib

I need present a grid-view in the web page, and based on the checkbox that each grid row has I want to retrieve and submit a value of the ID of each grid column. I'm using asp.net mvc and the mvc contrib grid, but accept suggestions on how to do via JQuery or Javascript too.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done, I've put the checks with the same ID of the "id" field and retrieveid the cheched with a foreach Jquery function...Worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to bind them to a list, take a look at this article from Phil Haack which will tell you how and give you a few ideas for other scenarios: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx